# Agent servlet communication

Tags: servlets, agents-jade

I just started to use Jade and I would like to know if it is possible to send a message from an agent to a servlet using JadeGateway, I have already managed to send a message from a servlet to an agent, but I want that agent to send back a reply and nothing seems to work for me.
Here is the doPost method of my servlet:

```
String champ = request.getParameter("action");
            try {
                JadeGateway.execute(new OneShotBehaviour() {
                    @Override
                    public void action() {
                        out.println("action");
                        final ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
                        AID theAgent = new AID("Agent47", false);
                        msg.addReceiver(theAgent);
                        msg.setConversationId("Agent servlet communication");
                        msg.setContent(champ);
                        myAgent.send(msg);
                        ACLMessage res = myAgent.receive();
                        if (res != null) {
                            System.out.println(res.getContent());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The servlet sends the data entered by the user in a jsp page to the agent.
Here is the code of the agent:

```
//The cyclic behaviour i added to the agent
public class ProcessExternalRequests extends CyclicBehaviour {
    private MessageTemplate mt;
    @Override
    public void action() {
        mt = MessageTemplate.MatchConversationId("Agent servlet communication");
        ACLMessage msg = myAgent.receive(mt);
        if(msg!=null){
            if(msg.getPerformative()==ACLMessage.REQUEST){
                String content = msg.getContent();
                System.out.println("Agent " + myAgent.getAID().getLocalName() + " Content = " + content);
                //Response
                ACLMessage res = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CONFIRM);
                res.addReceiver(msg.getSender());
                res.setContent("Bien reçu!");
                myAgent.send(res);
            }
        }else{
            block();
        }
```

My problem is that the agent won't send a message back to the servlet. What should I do?